# Database about a forum design issue

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, recursive-query, recursive-datastructures

I am currently designing a database about a forum.

The database will have for now the current tables - A table about the users, about the categories. The problem comes when I want to add the `QuestionAndComments` table. The `QuestionAndComments` table must have `UserId`(a foreign key pointing to the users table) and `ParentId` (will be null if it is a question and will have some value if it is a comment - the comment could be to a question or to an other comment) of the question but it must also contain the `CategoryId`(Foreign key referencing the categories table).

The problem is that if it's a comment it shouldn't have a `CategoryId`, it should have a `CategoryId` if it's only a question. Anyway if I try splitting the tables to table "Questions" and table "Comments" then I would ruin the self reference to the "QuestionsAndComments" table.

Surely the "Comments" table could point to the "Questions" table but then the "Comments" table must be self reference to itself and also point to the "Questions" table which is nonsense.

Comment: It isn't nonsense to have a comment point either to a question or to another comment.  You can use a table constraint to ensure that every comment has only one link or the other.  Because you're using SQL Server, you won't be able to cascade updates and deletions through this structure, though--the limitation on updates shouldn't matter if you're using surrogate keys, but you will have to handle any deletions with triggers or explicit code.

Comment: Your explanation about question and comments is not complete, do you mean users can ask questions about categories and other users might comment on these questions? or user can ask a question about a category, others might comment and this comment might be itself a question which is related to category or just a comment?